# Close a customized box at ESC keypress with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code for dialog box:

```
<div id="modal-dialog" class="no-display">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="close">

            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <h2><u>form</u></h2>
            </div>          
            <form>
                <label for="yourname">Full name:</label><input type="text" name="yourname">
                <label for="email">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email">
                <label for="message">Message:</label></textarea><textarea type="text" name="message"></textarea><br/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <p align="center"><button>Send feedback</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript :

```
$("#clickfeed").live("click", function() {
        $("#modal-dialog").removeClass("no-display");
    });
```

I wrote:

```
$("#modal-dialog").live("keyup", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 27 && !($(this).hasClass("no-display")))
        {
            $("#feedback-modal-dialog input").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("value","");
            });
            $("#feedback-modal-dialog textarea").each(function() {
                $(this).val("");
            });
            $("#modal-dialog").addClass("no-display"); //or .hide()
        }       
    });
```

The `ESC` key works only if an input is focused otherwise not.

I want to close `modal-dialog` box when pressed `ESC`.

Is a mistake in my JS code ?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Just curious, is there a difference here in using `===` or `==` when comparing key codes?

Comment: @Niklas Both are correct, but it's actually better to use `===`. It's stricter, and does not perform type coercion. Read more on Javascript Garden: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("html").live("keyup", function(e) {

if(e.keyCode === 27 && !($('#modal-dialog').hasClass("no-display")))

    escape_check();

}

}

function escape_check() {

$("#modal-dialog").removeClass("no-display");

$("#feedback-modal-dialog input").each(function() {
    $('#modal-dialog').attr("value","");
});
$("#feedback-modal-dialog textarea").each(function() {
    $('#modal-dialog').val("");
});
$("#modal-dialog").addClass("no-display"); //or .hide()


}
```

Comment: `$("html")` I missed it :)). My bad. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Binding to `$("#modal-dialog")` will not capture the ESC button being pressed if `$("#modal-dialog"` doesnt have focus.

You would be better off binding the keyup to the whole document so it would raise the keypress event regardless of where on the page had focus.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Its really difficult to debug this if you dont know about the focus requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. Try using `.on()` instead.

It works just the same. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I will use `on` instead of `live`. Thx for advice