# How do I hide or close the div box by click outside?

Tags: jquery, html, hide

This works fine. But now I want to add the functionality so that if the user clicks anywhere outside of the div, the div will go back to being hidden. One more question, can i use the same code IPade also...

http://jsfiddle.net/HNrCD/2/

How do I hide or close the div box by click outside?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#focus").click(function () {
            $('#hidden-item').toggleClass('focused');

        });

    });//]]>  

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#focus {float: left; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 5px;}
#wrap {
    width: 100%;    
    position: fixed;
}

#hidden-item {
  background: red; color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:15px;


  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


#hidden-item.focused {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <p id="focus">Click to Show/Hide</p>

    <div id="hidden-item">
        Hidden div...
        <br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        Line2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/CCmy2/

This is based on YogeshWaran's Answer! Up him.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. that's what i need..) working perfect...)

Comment: But if you click out of div it is toggled again in your example and not only hide. Look my answer below if it match better your initial request.

Answer (score 1):

try this selector **$(":not('#wrap')")**

```
$(":not('#wrap')").click(function(){
   // hide your div here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See my question and the marked answer:

[Close a customized box at ESC keypress with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030850/close-a-customized-box-at-esc-keypress-with-jquery)

I posted similar answer from Joffrey (with little modifications). Instead `#modal-dialog` can be any selector of div which you want to close it. And instead of `live` which is deprecated in new version of jquery, use `on`.

```
$("html").on("keyup", function(e) {

if(e.keyCode === 27 && !($('#modal-dialog').hasClass("no-display")))

    escape_check();

}

}

function escape_check() {

// here, reset any fields at closing box (if you have any) 

$("#modal-dialog").removeClass("no-display");

$("#feedback-modal-dialog input").each(function() {
    $('#modal-dialog').attr("value","");
});
$("#feedback-modal-dialog textarea").each(function() {
    $('#modal-dialog').val("");
});
$("#modal-dialog").addClass("no-display"); //or .hide()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `left:0` to `left:0px` in your toggle class.

Result using your code : http://jsfiddle.net/G5Yh4/1

For your issue change JS to :

```
var hover_focus = false ;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#focus").click(function () {
        $('#hidden-item').toggleClass('focused');
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
        hover_focus = true ;
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        hover_focus = false ;
    });
});

$(document).click(function() {
    if(!hover_focus) {
          $('#hidden-item').removeClass('focused');             
    }
}) ;
```

​
I think jQuery have a selector for "not hover", something like`.not(':hover')`. you can check there : http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Thanks... But i need to close "hidden-item" div by click any where out side the hidden-item div...